# Как в этом коде, в main добавить тип int и boolean( используя RandomList)?

Tags: java

Как в этом коде, в main добавить тип int и boolean( используя RandomList)?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomList<T> {
    private ArrayList<T> storage = new ArrayList<T>();
    private Random rand = new Random(47);

    public RandomList(T i, T i1, T i2) {

    }

    public RandomList() {

    }

    public void add(T item) {
        storage.add(item);
    }

    public T select() {
        return storage.get(rand.nextInt(storage.size()));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RandomList<String> rs = new RandomList<>();

        for (String s : ("The quick brown fox jumped over " +
                "the lazy brown dog").split(" "))
            rs.add(s);
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            System.out.print(rs.select() + " ");

    }
}
```

Comment: Никак, `int` и `boolean` являются **примитивными типами данных**, а в коллекциях и обобщённых классах могут использоваться только классы-обёртки (`Integer` и `Boolean` соответственно)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Никак, `int` и `boolean` являются примитивными типами данных, а в коллекциях и обобщённых классах могут использоваться только классы-обёртки (`Integer` и `Boolean` соответственно):

```java
RandomList<Boolean> rb = new RandomList<>();
rb.add(true);   // auto-boxed to Boolean
rb.add(Boolean.FALSE);

RandomList<Integer> ri = new RandomList<>();
ri.add(1);   // auto-boxed to Integer
ri.add(Integer.valueOf(2));
ri.add(Integer.valueOf("3"));
ri.add(4);
```

---

Также хотелось бы отметить, что конструктор списка с тремя аргументами можно переписать для произвольного числа аргументов:

```java
public class RandomList<T> {
    private Random rand = new Random(47);
    private List<T> storage = new ArrayList<>();

    public RandomList(T ... arr) {
        Collections.addAll(storage, arr);
    }

    // ...
}
```

тогда можно будет наполнять список без множественных вызовов `add`:

```java
RandomList<Integer> ri = new RandomList<>(1, 2, 3, 4, 5); // autoboxed to Integer
```

Answer (score 0):

непосредственно тип `int` или `boolean` добавить не получится так как это примитивные типы.
*Generic* в *Java* работают только для составных типов, однако для каждого примитивного типа существует своя обёртка

- `int` -> `Integer`
- `boolean` -> `Boolean`
  поэтому вы можете сделать так:

```java
RandomList<Integer> rl_int = new RandomList<>();
rl_int.add(1);
rl_int.add(2);

RandomList<Boolean> rl_bool = new RandomList<>();
rl_bool.add(true);
rl_bool.add(false);

System.out.println(rl_int.select());
System.out.println(rl_bool.select());
```